# IntelliJ Idea Android Projects including un-watned files in apk

Tags: android, build, intellij-idea

I have a complex app structure, main project has android libraries which have their own android libraries and jars.

Main Project

- Libs

  - Android Lib project A

    - Jars
    - Android Lib project B
  - Jars

For clarification I have an android library project which has an ActionBarSherlock dependency and Facebook dependency, I use this library project between a few similar apps.

In the past I was able to just add the libraries as dependencies and it would build only the android related files (src/res) but now it is including everything in the path (tests, docs, example folders, websites).

I'm not sure what changed but my apks are now being stuffed with a lot of files I don't want and I'm not sure where to specify to not include them.

note: The reason why I can't just "remove" the unwanted files is because I'm cloning down the repos with submodules.

I'm using IntelliJ Idea 11.1.2 and android r20

**Update:**
Here is a sample project of the problem I'm having: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/713581/TestDependency.zip

Comment: Does it happen with 11.1.3 RC available at http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11.1+EAP? Can you share a small isolated test case project to reproduce this problem?

Comment: I will give it a shot and get back to you.

Comment: Updated question with sample project. I also tried with the EAP and got the same results. I think this has something to do with /libs folders or just the way I'm adding dependencies but I can't seem to find a combination that is working and also not built into the apk at build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because you keep your modules in the directory named `libs` which is by default designed for the native libraries (usually `.so` files). When building the project all the files from the `libs` directory are included in the target `apk` file.

To fix the problem go to the **Project Structure**, select **Test Dependency** module, open **Android** facet settings, change **Native libs directory** setting to some other path (like `libs_` instead of `libs`). Repeat the same for the **TestLib** module, rebuild the project. Now the final `apk` size is ~486KB and files from `libs` folders are not included.

[image: Native libs directory]