# Reduce size of debug APK in IntelliJ

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea, size, apk

I am co-working on medium sized Android project with 9 Android libraries and 10 jar libs. I develop in IntelliJ and my collaborant works in Eclipse. In Eclipse the size of debug APK is about 2.5 MB, in IntelliJ it is 20 MB. How is it possible? Can I reduce size of APK in IntelliJ to make faster to upload it into device?

Comment: Not sure how IntelliJ build the apk, but maybe it's not using zipalign? http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html Eclipse and Ant use it by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An APK is a zip file. Change the extension to .zip and unzip it. See what is in it.

Comment: Thanks. I have done it and in IntelliJ APK dwells lib folder, which has 20 MB. Any suggestions, how to avoid it?

Comment: Cool! I have fixed the problem using this method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11571647/539284. Thanks for your advice!